# Deleting a file after X days does not work

Tags: ubuntu, cron, rm, time

I've tried multiple ways of writing this and I'm executing the script myself so it isn't the crontab that isn't working.
These are examples of what I've tried :

```
find /home/backups -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
find /home/backups/* -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
find /home/backups/ -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

I need the files to get deleted every day yet it just seems to not work.
Running `ls -ld /home/backups` returns a long file list - These are the first two files

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8284346 Jan 12 13:00 arksave-2016-01-12--01-00-01.tar.gz
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8295428 Jan 12 13:15 arksave-2016-01-12--01-15-01.tar.gz

Note that is more than one day old, and these are the last two files

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38016124 Jan 13 12:30 arksave-2016-01-13--12-30-01.tar.gz
>   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 38016163 Jan 13 12:45 arksave-2016-01-13--12-45-01.tar.gz

Comment: whats the problem though ?

Comment: The files just dont get deleted

Comment: What output do you get if you just run the finds, and drop the exec's for now.  Also, show us the outputs of `ls -l /home/backups` and `ls -ld /home/backups`, and tell us which user is running the command.

Comment: Ah, I changed the code to `find /home/backups/* -mtime +1` yet it prints nothing, even though im 100% sure at least ~3 of my files are older than a day. Ill edit the post with a bit of the output from `ls -ld /home/backups`. Root should be running the command

Comment: _When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago._ - this also applies to mtime. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem. I just found this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days) a second ago, i fixed it by using the code example the second answer gave `$ find . -mmin +$((60*24))`

Comment: You can do `find . -mtime +0` as well.

Comment: Use `-mtime +0` for at least 1 day old (more than 0 day old).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting 'TNW'

> When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

So to find a file that is only a day old, you can use either of the snippets below

`find /home/backups/* -mtime +0`

or

`find . -mmin +$((60*24))`