# How do I find files older than 1 days using mtime?

Tags: linux, scripting, find

I'm trying to remove all files more than 1 days old.Before I execute a script to remove the files,I try to find the files using mtime. however, I face same problem with my command-

My Current date is

```
Wed Jan 27 11:49:20 BDT 2016
```

My file lists are-

```
Jan 25 15:11 25-01-2016.txt            
Jan 26 13:05 26-01-2016.txt    
Jan 27 02:30 27-01-2016.txt    
Jan 25 15:11 dfk-25-01-2016.txt    
Jan 26 13:05 dfk-26-01-2016.txt      
Jan 27 02:30 dfk-27-01-2016.txt
```

I thought `-mtime +1` was supposed to list all files over a day old.

```
find /etc/output/*.txt -mtime +1
find /etc/output/*.txt -mtime +0
```

/output/25-01-2016.txt
   /output/dfk-25-01-2016.txt

```
find /etc/output/*.txt -mtime -1
```

/output/26-01-2016.txt
  /output/27-01-2016.txt
  /output/dfk-26-01-2016.txt
  /output/dfk-27-01-2016.txt

My desired out output is as followings,

```
find /etc/output/*.txt -mtime +1
```

/output/25-01-2016.txt
  /output/dfk-25-01-2016.txt

```
find /etc/output/*.txt -mtime +0
```

/output/26-01-2016.txt
  /output/dfk-26-01-2016.txt
  /output/25-01-2016.txt
  /output/dfk-25-01-2016.txt

Comment: mtime +0 should work

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe with formatting fixes, I'd be less confused. But why do you expect `-mtime +0` to show _only_ the files for the 26th? Maybe you mean `-mtime +0 -mtime -1`?

Comment: But I want to find files old more than 1 days. Using -mtime +1 should get the desired result. Unfortunately not got that...

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days

Comment: @ Otheus : I have edit my desired output. Now your confusion should be solved... and ofcourse  -mtime +0 should give me files for 25th and 26th.

Comment: Please use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your question properly. It's hard to understant what command produced what output.

Comment: I am a beginner with Stack exchange ...Next time i will use formatting tools format my question. Thanks for your advice. @ terdon

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two points: find "ignores fractional parts". I guess it calculates the number of hours, divides by 24, and integerizes the result (discards the fraction). So `-mtime 0` checks a file, compares the mtimes, converts to hours, divides by 24. If the integer part of that result is 0, it's a match. That means 0.99999 hours ago will match. Then `-mtime +0` matches any file whose mtime difference is at least 24 hours.

Second, if you want mtime to count calendar days, and not `n`-24 hour periods from now, use `-daystart`. So `-daystart -mtime 0` means *today* and `-daystart -mtime +0` means before today.