# What does the -mtime option for find actually do?

Tags: find

I cant find any documentation surround this option in google. I assume it looks for files created within x amount of days? but a quick and precise definition would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than searching Google for this, why not look at the manual on your system? `man find` will tell you what the option does, with the added bonus that it will be correct for the implementation of `find` on your system.

Comment: Let me guess, did you Google exactly `find -mtime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `find` manual:

```
 -mtime n
      File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for 
      -atime to understand how rounding  affects  the  interpretation  of
      file  modification times.
```

See also [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days) for an explanation of the rounding behavior.

Comment: I checked the man pages and did not see that option in there. Thank you for the exerp.