# Deleting older log files

Tags: shell-script, shell

There are some log files created after a certain amount of time with the time stamp.

```
/mylog/path
Log_file_2018-07-19-22-55-31Z.tgz
Log_file_2018-07-20-01-29-11Z.tgz
Log_file_2018-07-20-10-36-49Z.tgz
Log_file_2018-07-21-18-26-36Z.tgz
```

I need to delete older logs based on date. For example, I want only last 5 days logs and older logs should be deleted. Num of log files created daily varies. How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you consider using something like `logrotate`?

Comment: I do not need to 'rotate' logs. Just need to delete older logs

Comment: That is pretty much the definition of log file rotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do with  `mtime`  (modified time) in `find` command.

```
 find /mylog/path -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete
```

- `-mindepth 1` means process all files except the command line arguments.
- `-mtime +5` will check for the files modified 5 days ago.
- `-delete` will delete

Comment: Please note that `+5` does not mean `5 days ago`. `+0` means at least 24 hours ago. `+5` would therefore mean `6 days ago` or older. (Source: `man find`)

Comment: from `man`..... data was last modified n*24 hours ago. so +5 days means 5*24 hours ago...something fishy

Comment: Unfortunately find command inside the customer unit is not have fully functional. i.e, mtime option is not available.

Comment: @Ravi which distro are you testing... can you share the error in question.

Comment: /mylog/path$ find /mylog/path -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete

find: unrecognized: -mtime
BusyBox v1.19.4 (2014-10-08 20:16:45 PDT) multi-call binary.

Linux version: 3.2.54

Comment: Is there any other way I can find older files other than using -mtime?

Comment: @SivaPrasath `so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.` - From the man page. You can try it out by using `+0` too, you'll notice you won't see any files from today.

Comment: @confetti yes `man` page is not vaery clear for this thing, as mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200050/270935

Comment: Busybox did not had `-mtime` earlier. Rebuild it with `FEATURE_FIND_MTIME` and now I can user `mtime` in `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

Since your find doesn't have the `-mtime` option I think this is the most simple way:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# delete every file that's between 5 and 40 days old
for i in {5..40}; do 
    olddate=$(date --date="$i days ago" +%Y-%m-%d)
    echo "Deleting files from $olddate..."
    rm "Log_file_$olddate-*"
done
```

If you *always* want to delete log files once they aged five days but for some reason don't want to use `logrotate` you can use `cron` (`crontab -e` to edit crontab) to run the following script daily:

```bsh
olddate=$(date --date="5 days ago" +%Y-%m-%d) && rm "/mylog/path/Log_file_$olddate-*"
```