# How can I get files using find command

Tags: find, aix

How to use find command to get only files from the current directory (excluding subdirectories and its files) older than a day on AIX?

Comment: Please always mention your operating system! You already wasted your time on Ask Ubuntu because you didn't tell us you were using AIX and now you have reposted here (which is fine, AIX is welcome here) and you _still_ didn't tell us you're using AIX! I had to edit it in. The basic tools like `find` vary considerably between the different implementations, so you _always_ need to tell us what OS you are using. The shell you are using, ksh in your case, is irrelevant.

Comment: Similar: [delete folders older than 1 day](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/225842)

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that the implementation of `find` on your Unix has the `-maxdepth` predicate (it's non-standard, but often available), the following `find` command would do that:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +0
```

This would print the names of the regular files (i.e. not directories, sockets, named pipes etc.) whose modification timestamp was more than 24 hours ago to the terminal.

If `-maxdepth` can't be used, then consider

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -mtime +0 -print
```

This means:

1. If the current thing `find` is looking at is *not* `.` (`! -name .`), the current directory, then
2. *Prune* that path from the search path of `find` (`-prune`).  This stops `find` from even *considering* entering any subdirectories.
3. If the thing is a regular file (`-type f`), and
4. If its modification timestamp is older than 24 hours (`-mtime +0`), then
5. Print the name of the thing we've found (`-print`).

Regarding `-mtime +0`: On your AIX system, see [the note regarding the semantics of `-mtime`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm) to determine whether to use `-mtime +0` or `-mtime +1`.  If you want the UNIX03 behaviour, you should be using `-mtime +0` to find files with a modification timestamp of more than 24 hours ago (and set the environment variables `XPG_SUS_ENV` to `ON` and `XPG_UNIX98` to `OFF`, in accordance with that note in the manual).

By default, `find` outputs the *pathnames* of the found files.  This means that you'll get filenames prepended by `./` from the above command.  If you don't want that, then you will have to call the `basename` utility for each found filename.

You can do that like this:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -mtime +0 -exec basename {} \;
```

[In comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49539790#49539790) you mention that you'd like to compress these files.  For this, there is no need to call the `basename` utility.  Just call `gzip` (or whatever compression utility you'd like to use) instead:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -mtime +0 -exec gzip {} +
```

Depending on whether you'd like to do something further with these files, you may look for similar question on this site, e.g. [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

Also related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91206/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-how-can-i-get-files-using-find-command).

Comment: Is there any way using xargs to implement the same?

Comment: @Anony Not in any way that would help I think. Also, this comment section was archived in [a chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91206/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-how-can-i-get-files-using-find-command). Do consider using it.  Also note that I've asked _multiple_ times for the actual command that you are using. I can't debug _anything_ without seeing it. Do not post further comments in this thread, but do feel welcome to use [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91206/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-how-can-i-get-files-using-find-command).

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `-mtime +0`? See [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorted. Though, the `find` on OpenBSD seems to have different semantics for `-mtime` and you would have to use `+1` there rather than `+0`.