# Unable to make find command work

Tags: linux, bash, find

My Goal is to find the files and delete them which are older than 1 day. I am using the command to find(list them) with `find /trunk/logs/ -mtime +1  -name '*.log' -ls > $LogName` or `find /trunk/logs/ -mtime +1 -ls > $LogName`. And to delete I am using `find /trunk/logs/ -mtime +1  -exec rm -rfv {} \;`. Unfornately I am not successful, here is from the server. can you suggest what I am missing ?

```
[trunk@Brave logs]$ find /trunk/logs/ -mtime +1  -name '*.log' -ls
[trunk@Brave logs]$ ls -lhtr
total 1.3M
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  32K Jul 29 3:00 more.sh_2019-07-29.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  27K Jul 29 3:00 Web.sh_2019-07-29.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  85K Jul 29 3:00 Mount.sh_2019-07-29.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  38K Jul 29 3:00 OOM.sh_2019-07-29.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  21K Jul 29 3:00 lfy.sh_2019-07-29.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  29K Jul 29 3:00 SUP.sh_2019-07-29.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  64K Jul 30 4:00 Web.sh_2019-07-30.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  75K Jul 30 4:00 more.sh_2019-07-30.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  90K Jul 30 4:00 OOM.sh_2019-07-30.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk 203K Jul 30 4:00 Mount.sh_2019-07-30.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  49K Jul 30 4:00 lfy.sh_2019-07-30.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  67K Jul 30 4:00 SUP.sh_2019-07-30.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  42K Jul 31 5:00 OOM.sh_2019-07-31.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  35K Jul 31 5:00 more.sh_2019-07-31.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  32K Jul 31 5:00 SUP.sh_2019-07-31.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  95K Jul 31 5:00 Mount.sh_2019-07-31.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  23K Jul 31 5:00 lfy.sh_2019-07-31.log
-rw------- 1 trunk trunk  30K Jul 31 5:00 Web.sh_2019-07-31.log
[trunk@Brave logs]$pwd
/trunk/logs/
```

Note : I have tried same with `+2` as well , no luck. But If I remove `-mtime +1` I am getting the whole list like any `ls -ltr`

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92346/why-does-find-mtime-1-only-return-files-older-than-2-days)

Comment: Thank you , but that his/her question is about the behaviour of the command. For me, I am not getting the expected output with find command.

Comment: From the output and description the failure mode is unclear to me.  In my timezone those all would be older than one day?  How are you unsuccessful?

Comment: @tink , thanks for response. That is the problem I am facing. I am not sure why its not working.

Comment: Again: I see no problem. In my TZ this looks like the desired output.

Comment: I didn`t get it , are you also thinking like me why its not working or you are saying it should work and I am doing something wrong?